# Can delegation be implemented in any language or it is language specific

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

I'm currently trying to understand the delegation pattern and I was wondering if this pattern is language specific, in other words does the language need to have some sort of support for `Protocols`, `Interfaces` etc. in order for this pattern to work or it can be implemented in any language?

Swift Example:

```
protocol SendersMessageDelegate{
    func shareMessage(message: String)
}

class Sender{
    var sendersMessage: String = String()
    var delegate: SendersMessageDelegate?

    func sendMessage(sendersMessage: String) {
        self.sendersMessage = sendersMessage
        delegate?.shareMessage(sendersMessage)
    }
}


class Receiver: SendersMessageDelegate{

    var savedMessage:String?

    func shareMessage(message: String) {
        savedMessage = message
        print(message)
    }
}

var sender = Sender()
var receiver = Receiver()

sender.delegate = receiver

sender.sendMessage("Hello Receiver"

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocols / interfaces allow you to create a clean and generic specification of the interface between the classes involved, but they aren't required. Generally the delegating class knows nothing about the delegate other than that it responds to a set of methods, but again that isn't required - often there are explicit runtime tests to check if it responds to the target methods or not. Strictly speaking it also doesn't need to be classes.

So, any language where you can have multiple code files / 'objects' which refer to another could be described as a delegate relationship. The difference between delegation and composition or simple invocation can be woolly. Abstract interfaces help tip the scale towards delegation.

Comment: How hard would it be for you to convert my code example to not use protocols?

Comment: Your main problem would be convincing the compiler to be happy. Using the obj-c underpinnings, so responds to selector and selectors makes it easy. In pure swift it really is best to use protocols and you shouldn't really ever want a different approach...

Comment: Hmm, so if I understand this correctly `Delegation` can be done in any language but each `language/compiler` has its unique way of doing it, is this correct (of course, besides the difference in syntax)?.

Comment: the difference is in how strongly typed the language is. obj-c isn't, so you can easily convince the compiler to be happy (to check at runtime). swift is, so you need to do things in a way the compiler can see it's actually valid.

Comment: @ Wain Got it. One more question: Is it common or good practice to declare your protocols in the same file as the delegator class (Sender and SendersMessageDelegate)? I'm talking about protocols that will be used with delegation.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty common. swift doesn't have the same import setup as obj-c so it's easier to place them in different files.

Comment: So even though it is a common practice, in `Swift` having it in the same file doesn't help as much as in other languages and it makes more sense to put it in a separate file to make it more modular/reusable.

Comment: it's unlikely to be more reusable, the protocol is usually pretty tightly coupled to the delegator - but it allows an anonymous relationship to the delegate.

Comment: Can you please clarify the following, I know I know, I promise this is my last question. The way I understand it is that delegation is ONLY one-way communication/assignment, and if you need two classes to communicate back and forward in `iOS` you would do it using a combination of `segues (prepareForSegue) and delegation`, correct?

Comment: not only segue and delegation, there is actually very little forward communication there. think more composition and delegation

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Any object oriented language can have delegates. It's simply a design pattern that is more widely used and supported in iOS.

Wikipedia's delegation pattern article even has Java examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern